# If div scrolled greater than - JS event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I am working on a website which has full body slides, the body's overflow is hidden. If the slide's content is greater than the height of the user's screen the user is required to scroll using the scrollbar or by swiping downwards on mobile.

I need it so that if the user scrolls greater than (for example) 50px a JS event triggers and if the user scrolls back up another JS event triggers. This will allow me to hide an element if the user scrolls and the element reapper if they go back towards the top.

I have used the following which works for when the user scrolls but I need to be able to define the value for it to be greater than and then have the other event when it's less than the value.

```
$(".section").scroll(function() {
    $("#header").css( "display", "none" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

Any ideas would be massively appreciated guys!

Cheers
Liam

Comment: Use the `scrollTop` property to figure out how far down the user has scrolled.

Comment: So look at the scroll position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `$(this).scrollTop()`:

```
$(".section").scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
});
```